# Java: Is it possible to use swagger-core annotations w/o any adapters?

Tags: java, swagger, springfox

I'm wondering is it possible to build Swagger documentation based only on [swagger-core annotations](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/annotations-1.5.x) w/o help of any adapters like jax-rs or springfox?

Why asking the question: e.g. when using springfox it relies on Spring annotations like `@RequestMapping`, `@ResponseStatus` etc. Imagine I want to specify a POST method which returns 201 by default:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "some api")
@ApiResponses(value = {
                @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Created")
})
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
```

Without the last line springfox will generate the 200 status by default which I don't want to be a part of the spec. And ofc I don't want to add an imperative `@ResponseStatus` annotation to the controller.

I.e. I want to be in full control of the generated API spec which should rely on swagger core annotations only.

Comment: You can set the `useDefaultRssponseMessages(false)` and the annotations will work without having to specific `ResponseStatus`

Comment: @DilipKrishnan the springfox author by himself says ResponseStatus is needed, check https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/632#issuecomment-99104202

Comment: ouch, that is you :) So has it been fixed in recent versions?

Comment: tried with 2.8.0 - `ResponseStatus` is still needed to eliminate `200` default response.

Comment: Yeah that’s me . Might want to raise a bug for that, I assumed it was fixed, sorry.